# Change the terminal app for Docker Quickstart Terminal

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, iterm, docker-toolbox

I've just installed Docker Toolbox on OSX, and the first time I launched Docker Quickstart Terminal it prompted me to choose which terminal to open in. I stupidly chose iTerm. Now, having realised my usual terminal these days is Terminal, I want to change that setting. But nothing I do seems to reset it.

I've tried running the installer for Docker Toolbox again. I've also tried running the uninstall script from https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/uninstall.sh and then reinstalling. But every time I click Docker Quickstart Terminal it starts up in iTerm.

Can anyone tell me how I can change this preference?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After some digging, the default terminal setting seems to be located in

```
~/Library/Application Support/DockerToolbox/default_terminal
```

...and can either be set to `iTerm` or `Terminal`.

The simplest way to set it is to remove the file and launch the docker quickstart terminal, that will allow it to prompt for the default once again.

Comment: Ah thanks Joachim, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson This no longer exists in Docker Desktop 2.2. Any idea how to do  it in Docker Desktop?